# Combinatorial proof of Hamiltonian paths on the rook graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, combinatorial-proofs, chessboard

We can be sure that number of Hamiltonian paths on the rook graph for any single cell on $n\times2$ chessboard equals
$$
H(n+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 
           \binom{n}{k}
           \binom{k}{\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}}
           \left(n-\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}\right)!
           \left(n-\lfloor{\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor}\right)!$$
Is there a combinatorial proof for it?